# How do you manipulate the value of a variable through the use of an input text field and submit button

Tags: javascript, html, weather-api

I am currently trying to setup a weather API and i am having trouble with changing the city. I have my url setup in a way where I can manipulate the city passing a variable through to the address. What I cant figure out is how to get it where the user can change the variable with the use of an input and a submit button.

var city = 'calera';

('GET', `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=`
+ city +`&appid=a34f9192fd6fa82116ba2227981b319a&units=imperial`);

Answer (score 0):

You can get your input field's value following [this guide](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp). So itd look something like

```
city = document.getElementById("myText").value
```

In your [submit button handler](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) along with ur get request. Of course you would need to setup the corresponding html elements prior.